# Unity vuforia xcode (iOS: armv7, arm64)

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, vuforia, arm64

If you have built an app for iOS(armv7, arm64) recently using these softwares, care to share: what versions of unity, vuforia, xcode you used.

Comment: So, whats your question? Did you run in any problems with vuforia?

Comment: I was using unity 3d 4.6.1, vuforia 3.0.9 to build iOS app. Then used xCode 6.3 to archive. I have already published the app on app store last month. Now, I did few changes on the app, tried compiling the app on xcode; "link error for 64 bit architecture". So, compiled for only 'armv7'. Build was success, but, itune won't let me publish that because my app doesn't support 64 bit anymore. So, installed unity 5.0, vuforia 4.0. Then, Vuforia say they don't support iOS 64 bit over unity 5. Downgraded unity to 4.6.4. Now, xcode says it doesn't understand IL2CPP.

Comment: So, why didn't you put this information in you question?

Answer (score 4):

**Note:** This answer is based on the information from the questions comments.

---

### iOS 64-bit requirement

Since Feb 1, 2015 Apple forces iOS developers to supply a 64-bit binary when submitting new apps to the App Store.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01192015a

For app updates this got relevant on June 1, 2015.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=04082015a

So, you're right, you'll need a 64-bit binary to submit an update of your app.

### Unity3D 64-bit support

iOS 64-bit support was added in version 4.6.2

Source: http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/01/29/unity-4-6-2-ios-64-bit-support/

Unity coded a new compiler `IL2CPP` that is capable of 64-bit, and that's the only way to create 64-bit builds with Unity.
As this new compiler is quite new (and still has a lot of bugs), I'd recommend to stick to the latest version of Unity 4.6.x (or 5.x, if you want to). The newer version include a lot of bug fixes, especially for `IL2CPP`.

### How to make it work

We're using Vuforia SDK 4.0 together with Unity 4.6.6 (I'm sure it also worked with 4.6.5) and Xcode 6.3.1.

#### Create a 64-bit build with Unity

- Enter `Player Settings` ➔ `iOS Platform` ➔ `Other Settings`
- Select `IL2CPP` from `Scripting Backend`
- Choose `Universal` from `Architecture`

Note: The IL2CPP compiler doesn't really deliver feedback on its progress, so the build may freeze Unity for a couple of minutes (depending on the projects size). Just wait until its finished.

#### LLVM optimization level in Xcode

As Xcode stripped to much code by default, we needed to reduce the optimization level in the Xcode project.

- Click on the project ➔ `Build Settings`
- Scroll down to `Apple LLVM 6.1 - Code Generation` (alternative: use the search function)
- Change the `Optimization Level` to `Fast` for `Release`

See also: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/Performance/Performance.html

If you got this far, it should be working now ;-)

Comment: "Change the Optimization Level to Fast for Release" - do you have a source for this? What bug does this solve exactly?

Comment: Optimization means code stripping, and sometimes the compiler can not determine everything the actually needs, and will strip too much code. Lowering the optimization level will lead to less code being actually stripped, and therefore keep the needed parts (at least in this case). I added a source from the apple docs about code stripping / optimization.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was a bit unclear I guess. I was actually asking if you have a source why setting a lower optimization setting might be beneficial for Unity. I ask because I've only bumped into this being an issue once, and that was 4 years ago with a specific XCode version. My experience is that the compiler backend is rocksolid.