# XCode error when buiding for app store

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unity-game-engine

Since the start of 2015 apple have new restrictions that say you must have 64-bit support and build with ios 8 SDK. I built my code with Unity for IOS, then opened XCode and opened the file I just created through Unity. I built it inside XCode fine with no errors. I then go to archive it and validate it. It then tells me about the new restrictions that I have mentioned above.

It says to use the default architecture to build a single binary. I go and change the architecture to suit this. Then I do a fresh build and it gives me an error saying "File is universal (2 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice". I researched this error and it said to just remove armv7s from the architecture. I did this and built again.

I then get the error "missing required architecture arm64 in file ..... undefined symbols for architecture arm64". I know this means that some of my libraries are not supported for arm64. I take out arm64 from architecture and then I am back to the start where it says I need to build for 64-bit.

Has anyone come across this type of problem before and may have a solution.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30956833/unity-vuforia-xcode-ios-armv7-arm64/30969663#30969663

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a new build from Unity.From Player Settings -> Iphone -> Other settings -> Configuration . Under Scripting backend select IL2CPP and then under Architecture select Universal.